# Reduce the byte size of an image

Tags: python, image, qt, image-processing, qt5

I have many 1423x800 bmp images with byte size  bigger than 3M, now I want to change the format of them to jpg and reduce the byte size of each image not bigger than 256K, but also want to keep the best image quality in such case, so any good ideas on reducing the byte size of the image here?

P.S. The goal of doing these image operation is that I am going to customize the logon screen wallpaper of Windows 7

Comment: FWIW, you can find the optimal quality by trial & error. If you use a [bisection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) you can select a quality in the range of 65%-95% in 4 or 5 steps. Rather than saving all the trial images to disk, you can use a BytesIO object.

Comment: have you tried lossless jpeg ? you can try libjpeg or opencv for an implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged this with Qt and Qt5, I would use the `QImage` class to load the file, then call [`save()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#save) with the appropriate format and your preferred quality:

```
 QImage img("myfile.bmp");
 img.save("myfile.jpg", "jpg", 8);
```

You won't know the resulting size of the JPG until it's written, but 8 is a suitable value for an image that size in most cases.

Comment: img.save("myfile.bmp", "jpg", 50) seems ok!

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing one off conversions of `bmp` images to `jpg` format, I'd use the [convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) command from the [ImageMagick commandline tools](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php).

However, if you want to do this in one of your Python programs, you can use [Wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.1/index.html), which is a Python binding for the ImageMagick library.

Another option in Python is [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.x/), which also supports saving images in [different file formats](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html)

Regarding `jpg` quality, here's a good reference: http://fotoforensics.com/tutorial-estq.php